# How can I specify a list of floats in Realm js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, realm

I tried a schema (via realm-js) with 
    properties: {
        floatArray: {type:'list', objectType:'float'}
    }

but got "Schema validation failed... Target type 'float' doesn't exist for property..."

Is there a way to specify an array of floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectType` cannot be a primitive type. It needs to be an object that you have created. AFAIK Realm does not currently support lists of primitive types. See [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575) for discussion about this limitation.

Instead, you simply need to wrap your floats in a custom Object type. For example...

```
class MyObj {}
MyObj.schema = {
  name: 'MyObj',
  properties: {
    myFloat:  'float',
  }
};

class MyListOfObjWithFloatProperty {}
MyListOfObjWithFloatProperty.schema = {
  properties: { floatArray: {type:'list', objectType:'MyObj'} }
  ...
};
```